# How to get a String data array from firebase on flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

They're trying to get the fix and their positions from flutter but what I get is a string with all the data and not with their positions, i'm using BLoC

Firebase:
As you can see in firebase I have a data array
[image]

cloud_firestore_api.dart:

```
 Future<QuerySnapshot> getCites() async {
return await _db
    .collection('type_cites').getDocuments();
 }
```

cloud_firestore_repository.dart:

```
 Future<QuerySnapshot>getCites() => _cloudfireStoreAPI.getCites();
```

user_bloc.dart:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot>getCites()=> _cloudFirestoreRepository.getCites();
```

and here's where I send to call my function and what I get instead of an array is a string:

```
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:generic_bloc_provider/generic_bloc_provider.dart';
import 'package:/User/bloc/userbloc.dart';

class DatePickerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  UserBloc userBloc;
  QuerySnapshot snapshot;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _DatePickerScreen();
  }
}

class _DatePickerScreen extends State<DatePickerScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widget.userBloc = BlocProvider.of<UserBloc>(context);
    widget.userBloc.getCites().then((result) {
      widget.snapshot = result;
      
    });
    return  RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print( widget.snapshot.documents[0].data);
          },
        );
     
   
  }
}
```

output:

[image]

and if I print the size of what it brings:

[image]

when I actually have it in an arrangement that has 3 positions and its size devernial of being 3 and not 1,
Any way to get the fix right from firebase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use following to print length of cites.

```
var documents =
    (await Firestore.instance.collection('collection').getDocuments())
        .documents;
print(documents[0].data['cites'].length);
```

Replace `collection` with your collection's name.

Comment: thanks so much, I thought I was doing something wrong with my request